# An iterator returning all possible solutions to n-queen problem in Java - follow-up

Tags: java, algorithm, iterator, dynamic-programming, n-queens

(See the [initial iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120993/an-iterator-returning-all-possible-solutions-to-n-queen-problem-in-java).)

Now I have slightly improved performance of the iterator. Whenever we have set a queen at a particular board cell, the previous iteration sacrifices \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ time to check whether the position is safe. This one does the same in \$\Theta(1)\$.

(Everything needed for demonstration is [here](https://github.com/coderodde/n-Queens/tree/master/src/net/coderodde/fun).)

**QueensIterableV2.java**

```
package net.coderodde.fun;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * This awesome class iterates over all possible arrangements of queens on a
 * <code>n<sup>2</sup></code> chess board such that no queen offends another
 * one.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 25, 2016)
 */
public class QueensIterableV2 implements Iterable<Queens> {

    private final int dimension;

    public QueensIterableV2(int dimension) {
        if (dimension < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Requested dimension is not a positive integer: " + 
                     dimension + ".");
        }

        this.dimension = dimension;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Queens> iterator() {
        return new QueensIterator();
    }

    private final class QueensIterator implements Iterator<Queens> {

        private Queens next;
        private int stackSize;
        private final int[] state = new int[dimension];

        private final boolean[] verticalMarks = 
                new boolean[dimension];

        private final boolean[] descendingDiagonalMarks =
                new boolean[2 * dimension  - 1];

        private final boolean[] ascendingDiagonalMarks  = 
                new boolean[2 * dimension - 1];

        QueensIterator() {
            state[0] = -1;
            push(-1);
            solve();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Queens next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Iteration exceeded.");
            }

            Queens ret = next;
            solve();
            return ret;
        }

        private int size() {
            return stackSize;
        }

        private void push(int i) {
            state[stackSize++] = i;
        }

        private int pop() {
            return state[--stackSize];
        }

        private int peek() {
            return state[stackSize - 1];
        }

        private int getDescendingDiagonalIndex(int x, int y) {
            return x + dimension - 1 - y;
        }

        private int getAscendingDiagonalIndex(int x, int y) {
            return 2 * dimension - 2 - x - y;
        }

        private void mark(int x, int y) {
            verticalMarks[x] = true;
            ascendingDiagonalMarks [getAscendingDiagonalIndex (x, y)] = true; 
            descendingDiagonalMarks[getDescendingDiagonalIndex(x, y)] = true;
        }

        private void unmark(int x, int y) {
            verticalMarks[x] = false;
            ascendingDiagonalMarks [getAscendingDiagonalIndex (x, y)] = false;
            descendingDiagonalMarks[getDescendingDiagonalIndex(x, y)] = false;
        }

        private boolean isSafePosition(int x, int y) {
            return !(verticalMarks[x]
                  || ascendingDiagonalMarks[getAscendingDiagonalIndex(x, y)]
                  || descendingDiagonalMarks[getDescendingDiagonalIndex(x, y)]);
        }

        private void solve() {
            mainLoop:
            while (stackSize > 0) {
                int y = stackSize - 1;

                if (peek() != -1) {
                    unmark(peek(), y);
                }

                for (int x = peek() + 1; x < dimension; ++x) {
                    state[y] = x;

                    if (isSafePosition(x, y)) {
                        if (stackSize == dimension) {
                            next = new Queens(state);
                            return;
                        }

                        mark(x, y);
                        push(-1);
                        continue mainLoop;
                    }
                }

                pop();
            }

            next = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The performance figures are like this:

```
Duration of QueensIterableV1: 8534 milliseconds.
Duration of QueensIterableV2: 3529 milliseconds.
365596 boards generated.
```

I kindly asked in the first iteration not to review the actual algorithm, yet this request does not apply to this iteration as I am more or less done with it. Please, tell anything that comes to mind.

Comment: `I am more or less done with it` You seem to have been done with it within a day from presenting V1 for review - Feb 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find nothing worth mentioning about `QueensIterable` but the visibility of `final int dimension`, kept for its iterators:
`private` needs synthetic accessors from nested classes.

The first thing striking me with `class QueensIterator` is that it is `private final` - why prevent extension?

In the constructor, `state[0] = -1;` and `push(-1);` seem to be doing the same thing.

"The marks" for diagonals occupied are used in the order *ascending- descending-*, but declare in opposite order.
Use of blanks for alignment between the two isn't quite consistent.

The expression in `getAscendingDiagonalIndex()` is a bit over the top -
`x + y` should do.
I'm not exactly happy with getting an index to be used in another step, anyway:
Shouldn't that be `getAscendingDiagonal(int x, int y)` … `setDescendingDiagonal(int x, int y, boolean occupied)`?

There is code duplicated between `mark()` and `unmark()`, which are named for how they work. I prefer named for what they are good for:

```
        void set(int x, int y, boolean occupied) {
            verticalMarks[x] = occupied;
            ascendingDiagonalMarks [getAscendingDiagonalIndex (x, y)] = occupied; 
            descendingDiagonalMarks[getDescendingDiagonalIndex(x, y)] = occupied;
        }
        @Override
        protected void place(int x, int y) { set(x, y, true); }
        @Override
        protected void remove(int x, int y) { set(x, y, false); }
```

The overrides are to do with a strategic problem with "V2":
it looks created by copy&paste, duplicating a lot of code.
Rather, extract what's common between the variants at hand:

```
    abstract class NQueensIterator implements Iterator<Queens> {
        Queens next;
        int top = -1;
        final int[] state;

        NQueensIterator() {
            state = new int[dimension];
            push(-1);
            solve();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() { return next != null; }

        @Override
        public Queens next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Iterator exhausted.");
            }

            Queens ret = next;
            solve();
            return ret;
        }

        int size() { return top+1; }
        void push(int i) { state[++top] = i; }
        int pop() { return state[top--]; }
        int top() { return state[top]; }

        abstract boolean isSafePosition(int x, int y);
        
        void place(int x, int y) {}
        void remove(int x, int y) {}

        void solve() {
            mainLoop:
            while (top > 0) {
                int y = top - 1;

                if (top() != -1) {
                    remove(top(), y);
                }

                for (int x = top() + 1; x < dimension; ++x) {
                    state[y] = x;

                    if (isSafePosition(x, y)) {
                        if (top == dimension) {
                            next = new Queens(state);
                            return;
                        }

                        place(x, y);
                        push(-1);
                        continue mainLoop;
                    }
                }

                pop();
            }

            next = null;
        }
    }
```

```
    /** isSafePosition() iterates positions to check. */
    class QueensIterator extends NQueensIterator {
        @Override
        protected boolean isSafePosition(int x, int y) {
            // Check upwards.
            for (int yy = y - 1; yy >= 0; --yy)
                if (state[yy] == x)
                    return false;

            // Check in diagonal (up and to the left).
            for (int yy = y - 1, xx = x - 1; yy >= 0 && xx >= 0; --xx, --yy)
                if (state[yy] == xx)
                    return false;

            // Check in diagonal (up and to the right).
            for (int yy = y - 1, xx = x + 1; 
                    yy >= 0 && xx < dimension; 
                    ++xx, --yy)
                if (state[yy] == xx)
                    return false;

            return true;
        }
    }

    /** Keeps score of diagonals occupied. */
    class QueensDiagonal extends NQueensIterator
    {
        private final boolean[]
            verticalMarks = new boolean[dimension],
            descendingDiagonalMarks = new boolean[2 * dimension - 1],
            ascendingDiagonalMarks  = new boolean[2 * dimension - 1];

        private int getDescendingDiagonalIndex(int x, int y) {
            return x - y + dimension - 1;
        }
        private int getAscendingDiagonalIndex(int x, int y) {
            return x + y;
        }

        private void set(int x, int y, boolean occupied) {
            verticalMarks[x] = occupied;
            ascendingDiagonalMarks [getAscendingDiagonalIndex (x, y)] = occupied; 
            descendingDiagonalMarks[getDescendingDiagonalIndex(x, y)] = occupied;
        }
        @Override
        protected void place(int x, int y)  { set(x, y, true); }
        @Override
        protected void remove(int x, int y) { set(x, y, false); }

        @Override
        protected boolean isSafePosition(int x, int y) {
            return !(verticalMarks[x]
                  || ascendingDiagonalMarks [getAscendingDiagonalIndex (x, y)]
                  || descendingDiagonalMarks[getDescendingDiagonalIndex(x, y)]);
        }
    }
}
```

More things to try were keeping "the marks" in longs or BigIntegers:
Go `get/setA/DescendingDiagonal()` & `extends` rather than copy&paste.